# Should I avoid throwing Throwable when dealing with a method that throws Throwable?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, throws, throwable

I've got an `@Aspect` annotated class that is calling [`ProceedingJoinPoint#proceed()`](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/runtime-api/org/aspectj/lang/ProceedingJoinPoint.html#proceed()).
This method `throws Throwable` and thus the class looks something like this:

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyClass{

    @Around("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
    public Object myMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //some code here
        try {
            return joinPoint.proceed();
        } finally {
            //some more code here
        }
    }
}
```

Is it ok for `myMehtod` to throw a `Throwable` in this scenario where I have to call another method that `throws Throwable`?
Should I avoid throwing `Throwable` and somehow convert it to `Exception` or `Error`?

In either case I'd like to know why as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not okay to throw Throwable.  Errors and unchecked exceptions are not supposed to be caught;  Errors are serious or fatal system problems, while unchecked exceptions (usually) expose programmer mistakes.  Declaring a signature with `throws Throwable` forces callers to catch, and allows them to suppress, things which shouldn't be caught or suppressed.

If at all possible, you should fix the `ProceedingJoinPoint.proceed()` method's signature, but if you don't have control over that class, your own code should wrap it in a more reasonable exception.

How to wrap it depends on what you expect of callers of your code.  If any Throwable is likely to be a condition that no one can possibly do anything to correct or address, you might as well wrap it in an unchecked RuntimeException:

```
try {
    return joinPoint.proceed();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    throw new RuntimeException(t);
} finally {
    //some more code here
}
```

If you want to make sure callers handle all Throwables gracefully, you should create your own application-specific exception class:

```
try {
    return joinPoint.proceed();
} catch (Throwable t) {
    throw new JoinPointException(t);
} finally {
    //some more code here
}
```

The exception class is simply:

```
public class JoinPointException
extends Exception {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public JoinPointException(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
    }

    public JoinPointException(String message,
                              Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! The `ProceedingJoinPoint#proceed()` is part of the [AspectJ Project](https://eclipse.org/aspectj/) so I can't change that method's signature.

Comment: @VGR - Pesky comment - declaring a throwable does not "allow to suppress". Unfortunately you are always allowed to suppress any type of exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you use [Lombok](https://projectlombok.org/) you can use [@SneakyThrows](https://projectlombok.org/features/SneakyThrows) in order to rethrow a Throwable without declaring it.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class MyClass{

    @Around("@annotation(myAnnotation)")
    public Object myMethod(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        //some code here
        try {
            return proceed(joinPoint)
        } finally {
            //some more code here
        }
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public Object proceed(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) {
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

This is the only way I know to avoid both catching and wrapping a Throwable or a checked exception.

Comment: Adding to @AmitGoldstein 's answer- This trick will help us in situations we don't want to wrap a checked exception in e.g. a `Runnable` or don't want to propagate a non-useful checked exception e.g. `UnsupportedEncodingException` to the callers. But this is not a golden hammer to replace the `throws` clause.